# What is the scriptural logic behind the equality of 'Naama' and 'Naami'?

Tags: name, bhakti

The Bhakti literature emphasizes on the equality of 'Nama' and 'Naami'.For example, they say Lord Krishna and His name(Krishna) are one and the same.

What is the scriptural logic behind this? Also, if God is One with letters or Sound,He seems to be formless in essence, which the bhaktas do not agree with!

Comment: According to Tulsidas, the name of Rama is superior to both Saguna Brahman and Nirguna Brahman because by the name itself, one can attain both.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury yes i read that,Naam bara  duhute etc

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury And Tulsidasji accepts Saguna and Nirguna with equal respect contrary to some other Vaishnavas

Comment: Krishna was avatar of  - the Paramatma. He was in oness with Paramatma. Thus Nama, and Naami are one and same. Krishna is a Namma there because Krishna himself was Isvara. Thus, Krishna and his Nama are one and same.

Comment: My question is: A man and his name are different.So why God's name and God are the same?